# Not able to render the helm template without quotes

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have used almost all possible ways to render the helm template. But now I am out of ideas and seeking help:

values.yaml:

```
rollout:
  namespace: xyz
  project: default
  baseDomain: "stage.danger.zone"
  clusterDomain: cluster.local
```

manifest.yaml

```
apps:
  certmanager:
    source:
      repoURL: 'https://artifactory.intern.example.io/artifactory/helm'
      targetRevision: 0.0.6
      chart: abc
    helm:
      releaseName: abc
    values:
      global:
        imagePullSecrets:
          - name: artifactory
      baseDomain: "{{ .Values.rollout.baseDomain }}"
```

When I try to render the template using the below command in my main.yaml file that will produce the final result:

```
values: {{- tpl (toYaml $appValue.values | indent 6) $ }}
```

Expected result:

baseDomain: `stage.danger.zone` (without quotes)

What I am getting is:

baseDomain: `'stage.danger.zone'`

If I try to remove the double quotes from:  `baseDomain: "{{ .Values.rollout.baseDomain }}"`, I get the following error:

```
[debug] error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Values.baseDomain":interface {}(nil)}
```

Any help or ideas to achieve the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an expected behaviour by YAML.

One dirty and bad hack would be

```
values: {{- tpl (toYaml $appValue.values | fromYaml | toYaml | indent 6) $ }}
```

and then you will not see the single quotes.

However, This is not a problem at all even if you have `'` single quotes in your value. You can include this variable for example something like this below:

```
      hosts:
        - host: some-gateway.{{ .Values.rollout.baseDomain }}
          serviceName: gateway
          servicePort: 8080
          path: /
```

Then it will show you your variable value without `'` single quotes.

Example rendered output:

```
        hosts:
        - host: some-gateway.stage.danger.zone
          path: /
          serviceName: gateway
          servicePort: 8080
```